# How do I remove the right hand margin line in Android Studio (Intellij)?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-14

I want to remove the right hand margin line in Android Studio/IntelliJ. I have pointed out the line in question in the image below.

I searched Android studio settings and search Google many times.. but I couldn't find anything.

How do I remove that line?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easy solution to this :)

Go to File, then Other Settings, then Default Settings. Choose Code Style from the list on the Left, then General. Change the `Right Margin` attribute to be 0. This will remove the line.

Hope this helps. Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: I think something might have changed. I can no longer set this to zero, it jumps back to 100, or if I press down, I cannot get lower than 1. Instead I changed this to 1000. Get it out the way.

Comment: thanks buddy . I was not able to understand what it was.

Comment: This is not working in Android Studio 3.0, worked for me on earlier versions.

Answer (score 12):

For Android studio 3.2 this setting is now called: "Show hard wrap guide (configured in Code Style options)"

It is located at: Settings > Editor > General > Appearance

Comment: Correct. The silly developers named it "Hard wrap and visual guides" instead of simply calling it the "print margin".

Answer (score 11):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 2017

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- type "Appearance: Show right"
- switch the toggle to **OFF** using <kbd>Enter</kbd> or mouse left click.

  [image: Appearance: Show right margin]

Comment: Much more simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the editor.xml file for addtional settings.  The file is located (Windows 7) here:

C:\Users\YOURNAME\.AndroidStudio\config\options\editor.xml

Look for the setting, IS_RIGHT_MARGIN_SHOWN.  Its default value is true.  Change it to false and restart Android Studio.  This should hide the right margin line.

Comment: This works! Just make sure that you are using the correct version in **.AndroidStudio**, so for _1.5_ version it should be **.AndroidStudio1.5**, for _2_ it would be **.AndroidStudio2** etc..

Answer (score 2):

I found that Android Studio 3 wasn't accepting blank or 0 value in the attribute as per in [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4015623/alex-k)'s answer.

Try following steps:
From menu bar, select  `File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance`
and uncheck the `Show right margin...` checkbox.

[image: Removing the right margin in Android Studio]

Comment: This is the right answer. Android Studio creators are a bunch of people who don't understand design.

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1**

Currently in the Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 the option to hide the code editor margin right bar can be found at:

- `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance`
- Then unmark the option: "`Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)`"

[Print of option path on Android Studio settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Gub.png)

- Before unmark the option:
  [Print of editor before unmark the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Y29.png)
- After unmark the option:
  [Print of editor after unmark the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK58L.png)